# ReadWrite access to W10 partition in dual-boot

Tags: permissions, linux-mint

Installed LinuxMint 19.1 alongside W10. In Linux I cannot access files in ReadWrite mode on the Windows partition - this was possible all along up to Windows 7. I used to keep my data on the Windows side so I could access these from both sides... The W10 data is shown with owner being root... Any idea how to circumvent that? Thanks a lot as I need to keep W10 active for specific applications but prefer running Linux otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling windows fast-boot. By default it does some weird hybrid-sleep instead of shut down and that might be locking the drive. There's a guide here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 0):

In Linux in general only root can mount devices and therefore root only have write access to them. to overcome this you need to have ntfs-3g package installed which automatically does that for you. Or mount them with

```
mount -t ntfs -o umask=000
```

the *umask* will give everyone read/write permission.

Comment: I think `umask 000` can give `rw` if permissions are `xx6` or `xx7`.